# puppeteer with iframes does not return name when calling frame.name()

Tags: puppeteer

I'm having an issue in puppeteer where when logging the frame itself, I get this:

```
Set {
         Frame {
           _frameManager: [FrameManager],
           _client: [CDPSession],
           _parentFrame: [Circular],
           _detached: false,
           _lifecycleEvents: [Set],
           _mainWorld: [DOMWorld],
           _secondaryWorld: [DOMWorld],
           _childFrames: Set {},
           _name: 'frame_name',
      _name: undefined,
```

but when logging `frame.name()`, I get an empty string.  Also, I think there's something off with my timing logic as I feel there's a less hardcoded way of doing this than waiting for 5 seconds.  Thanks.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation(),
      page.goto('http://foo.com'),
    ]);

    await page.type('#email', 'foo@foo.com');
    await page.type('#password', '12345678');
    await (await page.$('#email')).press('Enter');
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    const frames = await page.frames();
    console.log('frame>>>', await frames[0].name());
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e)
  }
})()
```

Comment: What does the HTML code of the frame look like? Does it maybe not have a `name` or `id` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that frame has a `name` or `id`.
2. If so, you can use events or custom functions for waiting.

Helper function from [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1361#issuecomment-343748051).

```
    function waitForFrame(page, frameName) {
      let fulfill;
      const promise = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);
      checkFrame();

     return promise;

     function checkFrame() {
       const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.name() === frameName);
       if (frame)
         fulfill(frame);
       else
         page.once('frameattached', checkFrame);
     }
    }


    // 1. waiting for frame with name 'someFrame' to get attached
    const frame = await waitForFrame(page, 'someFrame'); 
    // 2. waiting for the frame to contain the necessary selector
    await frame.waitForSelector('#selector');
    const button = await frame.$('#selector');
    button.click();
```